# Is ASP.Net Server Control, Postback Architecture failed in current Web 2.0 World

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, architecture

What i am looking around me is the drastically change in ASP.Net Architecture. More and more company are following the approach of

JSON based wcf service in middle tier.
Plain HTML based UI tier with JQuery/Ajax.

No Postback at all, This contradicts the Default behaviour of Asp.Net Server Control/Code Behind Event handler/Postback.
I am a Asp.Net Web Developer for around 4 years, and concerned about the future of ASP.Net.

Is the Default Architecture of ASP.Net is Outdated at all? 
Does MVC or ASP.Net 4.0 Tries to solve the Issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failed is a bit strong a word for ASP.NET. Flawed is probably a better word. MVC certainly addresses the issues that you have raised. And more. Yes the default architecture of ASP.NET is now outdated. The fact that ASP.NET MVC sits on top of ASP.NET means that you can still use the productivity enhancing features of ASP.Net and any legacy code that you have in ASP.Net until the point where you are able to author your site in MVC quicker than you can in ASP.NET. This will happen very quickly.

Comment: Even in MVC, I think it's the postback architecture?

Comment: The MVC routing engine passes the request to a seperate HTTPHandler, so the normal ASP.NET page lifecyclye is by-passed. If you view the html here on StackOverflow you will see no postbacks. I believe it is an ASp.NET MVC site. Not a ViewState or doPostback in sight. :)

Comment: Your gauss is correct:
StackOverflow is runnin on 

Server          Microsoft-IIS/7.5
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)